# Why do I need to manually fetch params in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I am trying to render a partial with locals. Everything works well except that the passed value is never stored in the database, unless I manually fetch the parameter in the controller and save it.

View: topics/show.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'linktags/form', locals: {linktag: @linktag, topic: @topics.id} %>
```

Partial: linktags/_form.html.erb

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, topic) %>
```

Controller: linktag_controller.rb

```
def create
@linktag = Linktag.new(linktag_params)
@linktag.post_id = params[:post_id]
.....
.....
end
```

So why do I need to fetch the post_id parameter to save the value? Why does it just not save when I click on submit? The post_id parameter is also an allowed parameter.

```
def linktag_params
  params.require(:linktag).permit(:url, :name, :favicon, :post_id)
end
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for your form? Because it wouldn't work if that's the whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use form object as I believe you are using `form_for`

like `<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => topic %>`

Comment: Ah! This worked :) Thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as the timer runs out.